# Linksys AC 580 wireless usb adapter not working

Tags: wireless

I recently purchased a Linksys wireless AC 580 dual band, model AE6000.

I was told that there were many problems with wireless usb using linux. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 lts. But I figured I could give it a try. It did not work, I have been searching the web for directions or solutions on what actions I could take but I am coming up short.

Is someone else having this problem? If so can you help me with this or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: lsusb

Comment: Since this is an old question, I'll post a link to a similar question with answer here in case other people come by looking for a solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/584822/linksys-ac1200-wireless-ac-usb-adapter-install
Similar thread on Ubuntu forums:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2036219

Answer (score 1):

Hardware needs Drivers to work. To write a Driver you need basic knowledge about the Hardware. Since Cisco did not create OpenSource Drivers nor Linux Drivers nor openens up the Specs for this device, only a Hardcore Linux Developer could spend much time to analyse the Hardware and then write an OpenSource Driver for it. If the best people begin now, you will have a beta driver in a year or two.

To be clear: That will not happen. You should inform yourself before buying and only buy Linux compatible Hardware. It is a market Problem with the manufacturers. Help to solve this issue by reporting back to cisco, give your dongle back and get a new, linux compatible, one.

Tip: If a Hardware is advertised with "No Driver install needed" or similar, than chance is high, that a standard is used and it will work without any additional drivers on Win,Mac,Linux. Search for WiFi Dongles that explicit work with Linux BEFORE buying one. There are lots of them. Also check out this to find compatible hardware: http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/