# LinkSys AC1200 Wireless-AC USB adapter install

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb-modem

Purchased a USB adapter( LinkSys AC1200 Wireless-AC USB adapter/ model WUSB6300) for my Windows laptop and the installation on that was easy. Tricky part is getting it to work in my Linux environment laptop. Cisco does not support Linux with this device.Need to figure out if I can install this to my Linux environment somehow. Some details:

```
Ubuntu:             14.04 LTS  
lsusb:              Bus 002 Device 004: ID 13b1:003f Linksys  
Hardware at Issue:  LinkSys AC1200 Wireless-AC USB adapter  
model:              WUSB6300
```

Answer (score 8):

This can be done on a [command line terminal](/q/196212):

> This is a brand new device which needs a separate driver. Install it
>   via LAN connection:
>
> ```sh
> sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) linux-headers-generic build-essential git
> git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
> cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
> make
> sudo make install
> ```
>
> Load the driver and check:
>
> ```sh
> modinfo 8812au | egrep -i 'versi|filen|003f'
> sudo modprobe -v 8812au
> iwconfig
> iwlist chan
> ```
>
> Do not remove the driver folder. After a kernel update you need to
>   compile again:
>
> ```sh
> cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
> make clean
> git fetch
> git reset --hard origin/master
> make
> sudo make install
> ```

Be aware, that `git fetch` requires internet access to fetch driver updates from its source code repository, so you may want to do that *before* booting the new kernel.

([Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2200496) with some modifications)

Comment: sorry, noob here to Linux. Is this a command to enter into terminal?

Comment: Yes. I clarified that in the answer.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. Just bought this adapter and this kept me from returning it.

Comment: In my case `modinfo 8812au | egrep -i 'versi|filen|003f'` returned `modinfo: ERROR: Module 8812au not found.` I found using `lsmod | grep 8812au` that I got a result called rtl8812au rather than 8812au. Using rtl8812au rather than 8812au in the first two "Load the driver and check" lines did the trick. Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @David Forester after restarting it's not working anymore... any ideas?

Comment: @vicatcu: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. Thanks.