# Common method for installing Linksys ac1200 usb wireless router ineffective

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, usb

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and I bought a Linksys AC1200 wireless adapter without doing enough research, figuring I could get it to work. I have followed the instructions at
[LinkSys AC1200 Wireless-AC USB adapter install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584822/linksys-ac1200-wireless-ac-usb-adapter-install), as well as a few permutations thereof, all to no avail.

`lsusb` shows the adapter plugged into my usb. But nothing for wireless shows up when I use `lshw -C network`, only for my ethernet connection. I don't get any errors during the make or the install, but nothing seems to happen. I get no prompt, nor does the little network dash pop up. I'm not sure what else to try. Can anyone help? I can provide copies of whatever commands are necessary to diagnose the problem.

EDIT, output from `lsusb`:
The device seems to be

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 13b1:0045 Linksys WUSB6300 V2
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 093a:2532 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Gaming Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 056a:0315 Wacom Co., Ltd PTH-651 [Intuos pro (M)]
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I'm pretty sure the adapter is

```
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 13b1:0045 Linksys WUSB6300 V2
```

as it appears when I plug in the device and disappears when I remove it.

Comment: "I bought a Linksys AC1200 wireless router " The link is for a driver for a USB wireless device. It has nothing at all to do with a router.  From a manual: "USB port — Connect a USB device to share with other users on your
network or on the Internet. You can connect a storage device or a
USB printer." Please clarify your issue.

Comment: I apologize, I used the term router in error. I meant an adapter. It's purpose being to allow me to connect to wireless networks with my desktop.

Comment: Let's start by identifying your exact wireless adapter. With it inserted, please run the terminal command: `lsusb` Next, edit your question to show the result.

Comment: I've edited my original post to add the output from lsusb. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 13b1:0045 Linksys WUSB6300 V2

The driver for your device is 88x2bu. Let’s build it.

With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu.git
cd 88x2bu
sudo ./install-driver.sh
```

Reboot. Your wireless should now be working.

NOTE: Since you refer in your question to another attempted driver installation, I assume that the prerequisites git, dkms, build-essential and linux-headers are already installed.

**EDIT**: Please note that the driver has recently been updated. The new clone is:

```
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702.git
```

Comment: That worked! You're awesome. Thanks so much

Comment: Yes!  This actually got the WUSB6300 V2 working on my Ubuntu 21.10 system.