# lsmod/modinfo show rtl8812au driver (recommended for Linksys USB6300 AC1200 Wifi Adapter/Dongle) installed, lshw/nmcli Showing Nothing, Help?

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, usb

in spite of following exactly the instructions in the following answer:

https://askubuntu.com/a/642812

, although the driver appears to be installed and running according to `modinfo`, `lshw -C network` and `nmcli` show no Wifi device.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04, kernel version 5.4.0-77-generic, on a Dell Precision 5820 Tower Workstation.

`lsusb` shows:

```
(base) ➜  rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux git:(master) ✗ lsusb                 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0328 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 13b1:0045 Linksys 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lsmod` shows:

```
(base) ➜  rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux git:(master) ✗ lsmod | grep 8812
rtl8812au            1351680  0
cfg80211              712704  1 rtl8812au
```

`dkms status` shows:

```
(base) ➜  rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux git:(master) ✗ dkms status
nvidia, 460.80, 4.15.0-147-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 460.80, 5.4.0-74-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 460.80, 5.4.0-77-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu, 5.8.7.1, 5.4.0-77-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Any idea what to check or try next to determine why this driver doesn't seem to be working as recommended?

*EDIT #1* `modinfo` on `rtl88x2bu` shows:

```
(base) ➜  rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux git:(master) ✗ sudo modinfo rtl88x2bu | grep 0045
modinfo: ERROR: Module rtl88x2bu not found.
```

Comment: The driver for your 13b1:0045 device is 88x2bu, not rtl8812au. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `modinfo rtl88x2bu | grep 0045` Possibly a duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350238/common-method-for-installing-linksys-ac1200-usb-wireless-router-ineffective Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Now done, thanks for your speedy reply!

Comment: @chili555 Now after following exactly the instructions you provided at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350238/common-method-for-installing-linksys-ac1200-usb-wireless-router-ineffective, `modinfo 88x2bu | grep 0045` indicates that `0045` is located in the `modinfo` output, and my wireless now works!

Comment: @chili555 The "golden ticket" in this case proved to be installing the driver from `git clone https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702`. Last night, I tried installing the driver at https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu, but no luck :(. Is there some Wiki documentation for your procedure, which I now believe should be enshrined in gold? ;)

Comment: This may be close: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370462/how-to-troubleshoot-wifi/1370512#1370512 I'm glad your wireless is working as expected.