# Installing drivers for Linksys Wireless WUSB6300 Adapter on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, wireless, troubleshooting

I am trying to get the drivers for this working on my mom's computer, I have followed every tutorial that I have found and nothing has worked properly. Can someone please help me out? I am using Ubuntu version 20.04. I was recommended to try this [Common method for installing Linksys ac1200 usb wireless router ineffective](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350238/common-method-for-installing-linksys-ac1200-usb-wireless-router-ineffective)

I get this But the /remove-driver.sh commands and the many restarts has no results, i get an infinite loop of it telling me to restart

```
Running install-driver.sh version 20211212
Starting installation...
Copying source files to: /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.13.1
Copying 88x2bu.conf to: /etc/modprobe.d
cp: cannot stat '88x2bu.conf': No such file or directory

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.13.1/source ->
                 /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.13.1

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j2 KVER=5.11.0-44-generic KSRC=/lib/modules/5.11.0-44-generic/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl88x2bu: 5.13.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.11.0-44-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.13.1/build/make.log for more information.
An error occurred. dkms build error = 10
Please report this error.
You will need to run the following before reattempting installation.
$ sudo ./remove-driver.sh
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I regret to learn that the recommended git repository has very recently been superceded. Here is the new method:

```
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702.git
cd 88x2bu-20210702
sudo ./install-driver.sh
```

Reboot

NOTE: Since you refer in your previous question to another attempted driver installation, I assume that the prerequisites git, dkms, build-essential and linux-headers are already installed.