# Ubuntu Fresh Install requires ASUS USB NIC drivers, can't install without internet

Tags: networking, drivers, software-installation

I am in a conundrum. My fresh install of Ubuntu on a desktop PC does not have the required drivers for a network dongle. As such, I am unable to install the required functions to install the drivers (ex: make, dkms, etc...). A wired connection is out of the question.

If there is some way to install these from the install USB I would love to know, but until that happens I am in the dark.

For context, I have an ASUS AC53 Nano that needs drivers and the install instructions are [here](https://waynekhan.github.io/2020/05/30/asus-usb-ac53-nano-ubuntu.html)

Comment: For the Git repo, use a different computer to clone it to a flash drive, and then just stick the USB stick into your (offline) PC. You may need to mount it, but that is easy. Getting the `apt` packages are harder but do-able. The easiest way would be to use a wire. But if you really can't, check out [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/974/1438484) which explains how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but after reading the other comments this solution won't work for me since I haven't installed any apt-updates/upgrades.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you have the same device 0b05:184c ? If so, I think this is much better: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385922/installing-drivers-for-linksys-wireless-wusb6300-adapter-on-ubuntu-20-04/1385927#1385927 Can you tether your phone?

Comment: I wouldn't need any tools or daemons to run .sh would I?

Comment: Have you confirmed that you have the exact same device? I will propose an answer when you confirm the usb.id of the device from: `lsusb` Are you able to successfully tether your phone?

Comment: lsusb |grep -i asus gives the same device you are asking about, 0b05:184c. I am also able to tether my phone. And I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

With a temporary internet connection by tethering, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential bc dkms git
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702.git
cd 88x2bu-20210702
sudo ./install-driver.sh
```

Reboot. Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: If tethering was an option, I would've done this since I already have the instructions to do so. My question was how to install the driver on a fresh install, either through the installation USB or via some other way.

Comment: "I am also able to tether my phone." It is possible, although long, tedious and prone to error, to install all the prerequisites from the install USB. If you prefer the long, slow, tedious method, I shall add it as an edit. Here is a rough idea of the process: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069550/unable-to-use-wifi-card-16-04-macos-dual-boot/1069949#1069949