# Tried to install Linksys ac1200 and failed in the procedures described here

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I tried to install the Linksys ac1200 on my ubuntu 21.10.
I followed the procedure on [this post on here by @David Foerster](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584822/linksys-ac1200-wireless-ac-usb-adapter-install?rq=1). I got error messages while running make:

```
make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.13.0-21-generic/build M=/home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-21-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/osdep_service.o
/home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘isFileReadable’:
/home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/osdep_service.c:1951:25: error: implicit declaration of function ‘get_fs’; did you mean ‘get_ds’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 1951 |                 oldfs = get_fs();
      |                         ^~~~~~
      |                         get_ds
/home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/osdep_service.c:1951:25: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘mm_segment_t’ from type ‘int’
/home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/osdep_service.c:1952:17: error: implicit declaration of function ‘set_fs’; did you mean ‘sget_fc’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 1952 |                 set_fs(get_ds());
      |                 ^~~~~~
      |                 sget_fc
/home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/osdep_service.c:37:26: error: ‘KERNEL_DS’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘KERNFS_NS’?
   37 |         #define get_ds() KERNEL_DS
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~
/home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/osdep_service.c:1952:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘get_ds’
 1952 |                 set_fs(get_ds());
      |                        ^~~~~~
/home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/osdep_service.c:37:26: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
   37 |         #define get_ds() KERNEL_DS
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~
/home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/osdep_service.c:1952:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘get_ds’
 1952 |                 set_fs(get_ds());
      |                        ^~~~~~
/home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘retriveFromFile’:
/home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/osdep_service.c:1980:33: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘mm_segment_t’ from type ‘int’
 1980 |                         oldfs = get_fs();
      |                                 ^~~~~~
/home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/osdep_service.c:37:26: error: ‘KERNEL_DS’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘KERNFS_NS’?
   37 |         #define get_ds() KERNEL_DS
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~
/home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/osdep_service.c:1981:32: note: in expansion of macro ‘get_ds’
 1981 |                         set_fs(get_ds());
      |                                ^~~~~~
/home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘storeToFile’:
/home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2015:33: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘mm_segment_t’ from type ‘int’
 2015 |                         oldfs = get_fs();
      |                                 ^~~~~~
/home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/osdep_service.c:37:26: error: ‘KERNEL_DS’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘KERNFS_NS’?
   37 |         #define get_ds() KERNEL_DS
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~
/home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2016:32: note: in expansion of macro ‘get_ds’
 2016 |                         set_fs(get_ds());
      |                                ^~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:281: /home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/osdep_service.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1874: /home/rafael/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-21-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:1622: modules] Error 2
```

Then while running sudo make install I got an another error:

```
install -p -m 644 rtl8812au.ko  /lib/modules/5.13.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install: cannot stat 'rtl8812au.ko': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:1628: install] Error 1
```

Then I tried the procedure outlined in
[this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197612/ac1200-wireless-adapter-in-ubuntu-19-10) but without any success. This procedure went through without any errors, but the adapter still doesn't work.
lsusb recognizes the device:

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 13b1:0045 Linksys WUSB6300 V2
```

If somebody could help me here, I'd appreciate that a lot. I would love to have it running.
My best
Rafa

Comment: The driver is incompatible with the kernel.

Comment: That post is 6 year old.